# JAVA Mail and Office 365 hanging upon connection

Tags: java, office365, jakarta-mail

We have an application which heavily relies on JAVA Mail for sending out email messages. We have set the connection timeout properties as per below (set from Long values, are Integers required for this to take affect?):

```
props.put("mail.smtp.timeout",           1000L);
props.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", 1000L);
```

After some time the application stalls and never recovers from an Office 365 smtp account (only happens with Office 365). We enabled debugging mode in JAVA mail and the line it fails on is below:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.5
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp-mail.outlook.com", port 587, isSSL false
```

The socket timeouts don't appear to be working when this point is reached, the application stalls. Below is an infinite loop which keeps connecting to the mail server and then eventually gets stuck.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String smtpServer   = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";
    String username     = "test@domain.com";
    String password     = "password";
    int portNumber      = 587;
    Long socketTimeout  = 10000L;

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust",            "*");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host",                 "smtp-mail.outlook.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth",                 "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port",                 portNumber);
    props.put("mail.smtp.timeout",              socketTimeout);
    props.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout",    socketTimeout);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable",      "true");

    Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    };

    while(true){
        Session sess = Session.getInstance(props, authenticator);
        sess.setDebug(true);

        try {
            Transport t = sess.getTransport("smtp");
            t.connect(smtpServer, portNumber, username, password);
            t.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html), which says:

> The SMTP protocol provider supports the following properties, which
>   may be set in the JavaMail Session object. The properties are always
>   set as strings; the Type column describes how the string is
>   interpreted. For example, use
>
> ```
>     props.put("mail.smtp.port", "888");
> ```
>
> to set the mail.smtp.port property, which is of type int.

the properties should actually be Strings, but newer versions of JavaMail will also accept them as Integers, but not Longs.

Also, note that you can [get rid of your Authenticator](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes) since you're passing the username and password directly to the connect method.  And you don't need to set properties for host and port since you're passing them directly as well.